# How to add regressor to Prophet time series model in R

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, facebook-prophet, statsforecast

I have the following code for running Prophet currently:

```
df <- data.frame(ds = unique(wkld$ds), y = wkld$sale)

# Train prophet 
m <- prophet::prophet(df, changepoint.prior.scale = .001)

# Create data frame for future forecasting 
future <- prophet::make_future_dataframe(m, periods = as.numeric(730))

# Make predictions 
forecast <- predict(m, future)

# Get the predictions of prophet as well as lower and upper bounds
prophet_df <- forecast %>% dplyr::select(ds, yhat, yhat_lower, yhat_upper)

# Create uncertainty plot 
plot(m, forecast)
```

Now, I want to update the code to use add_regressor argument to add an additional field that impacts the predictions. The trouble I am facing is how to add the regressor. When I add the regressor before training prophet, it does not let me use the change.point.prior.scale argument.

Please help me figure out how to update this code to add regressor field such as "weather" for example